# How to select multiple rows based on another selected rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables (cars and car_images)

```
cars
----
id
brand
model
...

car_images
----------
id
car_id
name
...
```

Every car can have multiple images ...

What is the best way to select all cars with their images ?

That's how I do it with Native **PHP PDO**, but I don't know if it's the best and fastest way ...

```
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM cars");

$sth_images = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM car_images WHERE car_id = :car_id");

while($row = $sth->fetch()){
    $sth_images->execute(['car_id' => $row['id']]);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: use `LEFT JOIN` instead

Answer (score 3):

You can do LEFT JOIN so you get cars also if they dont have images

```
SELECT * FROM cars LEFT JOIN car_images ON cars.id = car_images.car_id WHERE cars.id = :car_id
```

UPDATE

If you need to work with either car id or car image id, above will not have the desired result. This would be better:

```
SELECT car_images.car_id, car_images.id AS image_id, car_images.name FROM cars LEFT JOIN car_images ON cars.id = car_images.car_id WHERE cars.id = :car_id
```

Corrected that again :)

Comment: But this query will results with a lot of repeated data !!

Comment: The first query would also return unuseful data with an overridden id. The second query would return a list of car id, image id and image name based on the car id you pass to PDO.